# Charging only ever reaches 95%

Tags: laptop, power-management, 14.10, battery

I am using Ubuntu 14.10. And my computer is always attached to an AC power source thus it is always charging. But I have noticed that my battery says it is charged when I click on the battery icon in the top-right hand corner of my screen, although it only says this in the menu, in the section that I see all of the time it only ever says 95%. Although about half an hour ago I disconnected and reconnected the AC power source and it dropped down to 94%, and even though in the pull-down menu it says "charged", it still has not gone up. I would have thought that charged would be at 100%? So why is what I am describing the case?

This is what I mean when I am talking about the pull-down menu and the difference between the two statuses:

[image]

Comment: How old is the battery? Some old batteries don't charge fully, and so the icon remains, as if it's still charging.

Comment: Well I got the computer brand new about 3 years ago. So the battery would probably be about that old. As I have not changed it since. I just had a look at its properties in its "Power Statistics" and it says that its capacity is "94.0%", although this is rather strange because most of the time I see it at 95%.

Comment: In case this is a problem with the specific model of laptop, what model is it?  Also note that 3 years is a fairly long time in the life of a lithium-ion battery - while it should still be working, it'll only be working 50 to 70% as well as it did when new (if treated well ie topped up regularly, not fully discharged too often), so a bigger issue than your problem with battery meter calibration will be its natural decline in capacity over the years.

Comment: @neon_overload actually something remarkable has just happened. It still says that its capacity is "94.0%", but now it says that it is at 100% charge! Have a look at this screenshot of the information given by the Power Statistics (includes model): http://i.imgur.com/kH9sHyu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit complicated and I don't remember all the details.  However, the percentage is only a rough calculation and it needs to calibrate to be accurate.  Don't spend a lot of time worrying that 95% is bad and 100% is good nor that 55% is a whole lot different than 45%. It calibrates using discharge charge cycles to the realities of the battery to make it's estimate.

Try this to get it calibrated again. Unplug your computer and let it fully discharge until it shuts off.  Then plug it in and start the computer and let it charge up fully while it is running.  Don't be afraid to try that more than once.  See if that doesn't help.

3 years is a bit of time and new batteries are very inexpensive now-a-days.  Time how long it takes for your computer to shut off.  If the battery dies in 30 minutes you need a new one.  If it goes for a few hours, you're golden.  If it is weak, you might cycle it through a few discharge/charge cycles to see if the battery recovers. Particularly if it is NiCad batteries cycling it might help, not so much LiIon. I just ordered a new battery for my Asus 1005HA and it was $9.  Hard for an old guy to understand how they can be so cheep.